# Where do I report bugs in the code examples of the sklearn documentation?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

If a code example of the documentation does not work as specified, where would I report this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're talking about their official documentation, I'd submit an issue on their github: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues

Or, if you are able to fix the error, submit a PR.